# Why is purebasic chilkat module 30 day trial activation failing syntax?

Tags: chilkat

Attempted to activate the 30 day trial, on purebasic version 5.70 LTS  but using the posted code,  returns the following error when checking syntax.  (using 32bit version on 64bit w7 machine if that makes any difference)

I'm using:

> Dim glob As new Chilkat.Global glob.UnlockBundle("Start my 30 day
>   trial")

and get the error below:

> line 4" 'Dim' systax is: Dim Name(nb).

Answer (score 1):

Dim is used to define arrays. To define an array of 3 strings, you write

```
Dim names.s(2)
```

- The .s indicates that it is an array of strings.
- The 2 indicates the highest index available. So, counting from 0, it means three slots : 0, 1, and 2.

According to the [PureBasic module](https://www.example-code.com/purebasic/global_unlock.asp) of the Chilkat website, to unlock the bundle, you should follow the example below.

```
IncludeFile "CkGlobal.pb"

Procedure ChilkatExample()

    ; The Chilkat API can be unlocked for a fully-functional 30-day trial by passing any
    ; string to the UnlockBundle method.  A program can unlock once at the start. Once unlocked,
    ; all subsequently instantiated objects are created in the unlocked state. 
    ; 
    ; After licensing Chilkat, replace the "Anything for 30-day trial" with the purchased unlock code.
    ; To verify the purchased unlock code was recognized, examine the contents of the LastErrorText
    ; property after unlocking.  For example:
    glob.i = CkGlobal::ckCreate()
    If glob.i = 0
        Debug "Failed to create object."
        ProcedureReturn
    EndIf

    success.i = CkGlobal::ckUnlockBundle(glob,"Anything for 30-day trial")
    If success <> 1
        Debug CkGlobal::ckLastErrorText(glob)
        CkGlobal::ckDispose(glob)
        ProcedureReturn
    EndIf

    status.i = CkGlobal::ckUnlockStatus(glob)
    If status = 2
        Debug "Unlocked using purchased unlock code."
    Else
        Debug "Unlocked in trial mode."
    EndIf

    ; The LastErrorText can be examined in the success case to see if it was unlocked in
    ; trial more, or with a purchased unlock code.
    Debug CkGlobal::ckLastErrorText(glob)


    CkGlobal::ckDispose(glob)


    ProcedureReturn
EndProcedure
```